# Booting old server with GPT disk

Tags: linux, boot, gpt

I have an old HP proliant server with regular BIOS.

I'm planning to replace the 1TB system disk with a 4TB in it since the old DOS based partition table only supports 2TB I planning to put GPT and install Debian on it.

Will the server be able to boot with regular BIOS from such a disks?

Thats not a question if the server will be able to see the disks because I have 10TB and other large disks in other slots where I use the disks as raw for VMs so thats not an issue.

If NOT is there still a workaround to be able to utilize the remaining space on the disk?

For example I create the regular DOS MBR for the first 2TB (the system will surely boot and work) and somehow utilize the rest of the space after it booted?

Comment: GPT boot devices should run smoothly with a legacy bios as long as you use linux, see also https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-new-guid-partition-table-linux-goodbye-ancient-mbr/